# Angular custom directives with inline template

Tags: angularjs

i am working with this custom directive from here plnkr.co/edit/O3T7MJuwSvcG04CRvVWB it is working but when i paste the whole thing in `jsfiddle` and convert external template to inline then it is not working.

this is small code snippet of inline template

```
templateUrl: '<div class="dropdown searchable-multi-select" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" dropdown-toggle data-target="#"
        tooltip="{{ commaDelimitedSelected() }}" ng-class="{'disabled': readOnly}">

        <span class="limit-ellipsis" ng-style="{ 'width' : width }">
            <small ng-class="{'text-muted': commaDelimitedSelected() === 'Nothing Selected'}">
                {{ commaDelimitedSelected() }}
            </small>
            <b class="caret" ng-if="!readOnly && allItems.length"></b>
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul ng-if="!readOnly && allItems.length" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form form-control" role="menu">
        <li><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Search"></li>
        <li ng-repeat="item in ::allItems track by $index"
            ng-hide="searchQuery.length && item[displayAttr].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) < 0">
            <label class="checkbox clickable" ng-click="updateSelectedItems(item)"
                ng-class="{'text-success': isItemSelected(item) }">

                {{ item[displayAttr] }}
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right clickable"
                    ng-show="isItemSelected(item)"></span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
',
```

is there any error or anything missing for which code is not working. here is full code https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/xu7db29x/ please have a look and tell me what i am missing for which code is not working.

Comment: Change 
`templateUrl`

 to

 `template` in your directive.

Comment: i did the change but still no output is coming. :( anyone would mind to see my jsfiddle link . thanks

Comment: in jsFiddle sample you not include angular js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tidied up your directive, that was moaning a lot:

```
app.directive("searchableMultiselect", function($timeout) {
    return {
        template: '<div class="dropdown searchable-multi-select" dropdown on-toggle="toggled(open)">'+
        '<a class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" dropdown-toggle data-target="#"'+
    'tooltip="{{ commaDelimitedSelected() }}" ng-class="{\'disabled\': readOnly}">'+

        '<span class="limit-ellipsis" ng-style="{ \'width\' : width }">'+
        '<small ng-class="{\'text-muted\': commaDelimitedSelected() === \'Nothing Selected\'}">'+
        '{{ commaDelimitedSelected() }}'+
    '</small>'+                           
    '<b class="caret" ng-if="!readOnly && allItems.length"></b>'+
        '</span>'+
        '</a>'+
        '<ul ng-if="!readOnly && allItems.length" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form form-control" role="menu">'+
        '<li><input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchQuery" placeholder="Search"></li>'+
        '<li ng-repeat="item in ::allItems track by $index"'+
    'ng-hide="searchQuery.length && item[displayAttr].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchQuery.toLowerCase()) < 0">'+
        '<label class="checkbox clickable" ng-click="updateSelectedItems(item)"'+
    'ng-class="{\'text-success\': isItemSelected(item) }">'+

        '{{ item[displayAttr] }}'+
    '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove pull-right clickable"'+
    'ng-show="isItemSelected(item)"></span>'+
        '</label>'+
        '</li>'+
        '</ul>'+
        '</div>',
    restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
        displayAttr: '@',
            selectedItems: '=',
            allItems: '=',
            readOnly: '=',
            addItem: '&',
            removeItem: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('click', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        });

        scope.width = element[0].getBoundingClientRect();

        scope.updateSelectedItems = function(obj) {
            var selectedObj;
            for (i = 0; typeof scope.selectedItems !== 'undefined' && i < scope.selectedItems.length; i++) {
                if (scope.selectedItems[i][scope.displayAttr].toUpperCase() === obj[scope.displayAttr].toUpperCase()) {
                    selectedObj = scope.selectedItems[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( typeof selectedObj === 'undefined' ) {
                scope.addItem({item: obj});
            } else {
                scope.removeItem({item: selectedObj});
            }
        };

        scope.isItemSelected = function(item) {
            if ( typeof scope.selectedItems === 'undefined' ) return false;

            var tmpItem;
            for (i=0; i < scope.selectedItems.length; i++) {
                tmpItem = scope.selectedItems[i];
                if ( typeof tmpItem !== 'undefined'
                    &&  typeof tmpItem[scope.displayAttr] !== 'undefined'
                    &&  typeof item[scope.displayAttr] !== 'undefined'
                    &&  tmpItem[scope.displayAttr].toUpperCase() === item[scope.displayAttr].toUpperCase() ) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        };

        scope.commaDelimitedSelected = function() {
            var list = "";
            angular.forEach(scope.selectedItems, function (item, index) {
                list += item[scope.displayAttr];
                if (index < scope.selectedItems.length - 1) list += ', ';
            });
            return list.length ? list : "Nothing Selected";
        }
    }
}
});
```

However there are further errors, but please take a look. At least there is a drop down now:

[fiddle-dee-dee](https://jsfiddle.net/030usqz3/)

Comment: i check your fiddle and it is working. would u tell me what u change for which it is working. what was mistake in my code ?

Comment: The original template didn't have any line concatenation and so the template was not being understood. A new line was being treated as a new statement and of course wasn't working, I also had to escape some of the single quotes that were also confusing the issue. If you take my snippet above and compare it with yours you will see the exact changes. (use winmerge for instance).

Answer (score 2):

Use `template` instead of `templateUrl`. ;)

Comment: i did the change but still no output is coming. :( anyone would mind to see my jsfiddle link . thanks

Comment: check your console, there must be other errors too.

Comment: Add angular to the fiddle, also fix the template. way too many errors